how to create error rate table in grafana using http_server_requests_seconds_count
I have metrics which is giving count for all incoming request http_server_requests_seconds_count. My requirement is to create table in grafana dashboard with 4 columns 1st column to show uri, 2nd col to show count of request with status code 500 for uri, 3rd col to show count of request with status code 400 for uri, 2nd col to show count of request with status code request other than 400 and 500 but not 200 or 300, last column should show average count for uri.
How can i can create it using table visualization?
I tried adding multiple queries for each case using http_server_requests_seconds_count but not able to map each query to different column

I’m going to make a couple of assumptions to fill in some gaps:

From the name, it sounds like your metric is a counter, and I'm going to assume that it has labels for uri and status_code.
I'm not sure what "average count for uri" means in the last column, so I'm going to assume that this means "request over the time window"

The way we can solve this problem is by calculating several different quantities for each URI, merging them together, and then formatting the result.
First, let's set up a table visualization.

In grafana, create a new dashboard if necessary and add a new Panel
Set the Panel type to table
In the query options, set the Format to Table and the Type to Instant. This will format the prometheus data in a way that the table can use it.

Next, we need to create a prometheus query to get a count of the requests by uri over the target time period. Let's use sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[$__range])) by (uri). Here's how the query works:

http_server_requests_seconds_count is your metric, which I'm assuming is a counter.
$__range is the duration of time given in the time drop down in the top right, and [$__range] is telling prometheus to take a slice of the time series equal of that size.
counter values aren't useful in their raw form, so we need to process it with rate or increase to make it useful. increase is going to tell us how many requests happened over the timespan given by $__range.
finally sum(...) by (uri) is going to do a breakdown of the data by uri and tell us how many requests happened for each.

The result should be the total number of requests for each endpoint that happened during the target time window.
Next, we need to repeat the process for the other quantities that you care about.

Duplicate the first query 3 times, giving 4 total. Make sure that Format=Table and Type=Instant for all four.
Let's modify the second one to count the 500 requests. We can do this by using the same calculation and just by filtering the intial metric on status_code=500 like so: sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status_code="500"}[$__range])) by (uri)
Let's do something similar in the third query for 400 requests: sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status="400"}[$__range])) by (uri)
For "responses besides 500 and 400 but not 200 or 300 either", we can modify the query to filter out those values: sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!~"200|300|400|500"}[$__range])) by (uri)

To get all of these values on the same page in the table, we need to do a merge operation. Under the Transformations tab, add a "Merge series/table" transformation. The result should be a table giving a breakdown by URI with the four values you're looking for.
Finally, we need to do a bit of cleanup to make the table more readable. We can do this by adding another Reorganize Columns transformation. I would recommend the following cleanup actions

Hide the time column since it just shows the current time
Rename Value #A to Total Requests, Value B to "500 Responses", and likewise for Values C and D.

Here’s a screenshot of the settings:


Here’s the final result:

